# Navegar proyecto sin carpeta dist en Angular8

Tags: visual-studio, webapi, angular8

en angular 8, dentro de un proyecto de visual studio con web api, ejecuto

```
ng build --prod
```

Me crea la carpeta /dist y debo navegarlo asi:

http://localhost:51980/adminweb/dist/adminweb/index.html
adminweb esta dentro del proyecto de Visual Studio, luego al hacer el build me genera dist y adminweb nuevamente, como hago para navegar el sitio asi?
http://localhost:51980/adminweb/index.html
Muchas Gracias